# XSLT String Split on Attribute Value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How do I split the attribute value in XSLT to get the last substring?

Input.xml

```
<class name="apps.webdriver.tests.mkl.CreateLeadTest">
```

Expected output:

```
CreateLeadTest
```

Tried below (XSL):

```
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@name, '.')"/>
</xsl:attribute>


Didn't work.
```

Comment: Where to put the call-template function in the xsl?

Comment: @InsecureNoob - Replace your `xsl:value-of` with the `xsl:call-template`.

Comment: @InsecureNoob, your answer does work! You haven't included much of the context around your code, but check out your working solution with an example set-up here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8W